# Trouble understanding a protocol definition

Tags: c++, postgresql, protocols

I'm reading the Postgresql wire protocol and having trouble implementing a section, related to simple queries where the [spec](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/protocol-message-formats.html) says:

```
Query (F)
  Byte1('Q')
    Identifies the message as a simple query.

  Int32
    Length of message contents in bytes, including self.

  String
    The query string itself.
```

I came up with the following in C++:

```
(std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >) $0 = size=31 {
  [0] = 'Q'
  [1] = '\0'
  [2] = '\0'
  [3] = '\0'
  [4] = '\x1f'
  [5] = 's'
  [6] = 'e'
  [7] = 'l'
  [8] = 'e'
  [9] = 'c'
  [10] = 't'
  [11] = ' '
  [12] = '*'
  [13] = ' '
  [14] = 'f'
  [15] = 'r'
  [16] = 'o'
  [17] = 'm'
  [18] = ' '
  [19] = 'd'
  [20] = 'e'
  [21] = 'p'
  [22] = 'a'
  [23] = 'r'
  [24] = 't'
  [25] = 'm'
  [26] = 'e'
  [27] = 'n'
  [28] = 't'
  [29] = 's'
  [30] = '\0'
}
```

But I always get an error from the server:

```
EJSERRORC08P01Minvalid message formatFpqformat.cL652Rpq_getmsgendETSFATALC08P01Minvalid frontend message type 0Fpostgres.cL484RSocketBackend
```

At this point I'm tired of throwing different versions of this vector at the server to always get the same result, so I assume my interpretation of the spec is wrong. Can you show me in code how this would be done? Not the algo to generate a message, just a valid message.

Comment: I don't know anything about postgresql wire protocol, but: 1) you set length to 27 even though entire message is 28 bytes long; 2) maybe it has to do something with byte order of Int32?

Comment: @gudok Copied wrong vector.

Comment: @gudok - client and server are on the same machine so this shouldn't be a problem, no?

Comment: Your message looks ok (except the legth should actually be 30 instead of 31). Could ou show some more of your code? What do Wireshark or tcpdump say about the bytes that actually get transferred?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm using socat to listen to the socket connection and the output _seems_ to be the same I get from psql, which I recorded with tcpdump: https://gist.github.com/ruipacheco/cf6633bef88c179aef54ebace4669f5b

Also, the vector starts at 0 and ends in 30 so the length is 31, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't share your code, I cannot say where you went wrong.

Your message is fine, except that the length should be 30 (`'\x1e'`) instead of 31 (`'\x1f'`) – according to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-MESSAGE-CONCEPTS), the “message-type byte” should not be counted.

I tried it out with C on Linux, and it worked for me.

I sent the message with `send()` over the socket I got with `PQsocket()`, and I got a response that consisted of:

1. One *RowDescription* message (type `'T'`) describing the columns.
2. One *DataRow* message (type `'D'`) per returned column.
3. One *Close* message (type `'C'`) closing the statement.
4. One *ReadyForQuery* (type `'Z'`) message.

For the record, here is the C code I used:

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* PostgreSQL database connection */
    PGconn *conn;
    /* socket for the database connection */
    int s;
    /* simple select statement to send over the socket */
    unsigned char stmt[] = "Q\0\0\0\030select * from amaaa";
    /* buffer for the server response */
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t len, i;

    /* connect to the database */
    conn = PQconnectdb("");
    if (conn == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory connecting to PostgreSQL.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQfinish(conn);
        return 1;
    }

    /* get the TCP socket that corresponds to the connection */
    if ((s = PQsocket(conn)) <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection is not open.\n");
        PQfinish(conn);
        return 1;
    }

    /* send the simple select statement */
    if (-1 == send(s, stmt, sizeof(stmt), 0))
    {
        perror("Error in send(2)");
        PQfinish(conn);
        return 1;
    }

    /*
     * The following is oversimplified.
     * In reality, you'd have to call recv(2) until you have
     * the complete response.
     * But I don't want to bother with analyzing the response
     * and hope that it comes in a single packet.
     */

    /* receive the response */
    if (-1 == (len = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZE, MSG_WAITALL)))
    {
        perror("Error in recv(2)");
        PQfinish(conn);
        return 1;
    }

    /* print the server response */
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        if (buf[i] >= ' ' && buf[i] <= 'z')
            printf("%02X(%c) ", buf[i], buf[i]);
        else
            printf("%02X ", buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* close the database connection */
    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as it has given me a good idea of what to do next.

Comment: I'm also getting the socket but getting the same error. Can you paste the code you wrote as a guide?

Comment: Right, your code won't work. Even created a table called amaaa. I still get the same error as my original answer. The strange thing is that the whole authentication handshake works fine.

Comment: My code works fine on Linux with PostgreSQL 9.6. If you specify what you mean by "won't work", maybe I can help.

Comment: I'm on the latest OSX with the latest Postgres 9.5. I moved your code into a function instead of calling it from main because I'm running it from unit tests and since my db is configured for "trust" I added a conninfo string.

The connection goes well but when the query is sent I get this reply from the server: https://gist.github.com/ruipacheco/71286c5cb20971b7d012564e37e8a245

Comment: The problem is that you send the *Terminate* message right after the *Query* message. You have to wait for the *ReadyForQuery* message from the server before you can send another message. Looks like you didn't execute the `select(2)` or `recv(2)` call successfully. By the way, the `select(2)` is not really needed. I'll simplify my example.

Comment: You didn't set the socket to non-blocking mode, did you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130686/discussion-between-ruipacheco-and-laurenz-albe).